# add transport to Mule without Maven

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to import the following transport into my app (to use it as an endpoint):
https://github.com/QVCItalia/mule-transport-as2

However, it only talks about using Maven and adding it as a dependency. I do not use Maven, and so I'm not sure how I can import the transport into my project.

Is there another way to do this? If not, are there other AS2 solutions for Mule?

Thank you,

Comment: Well, download the libraries on your own and add them to the classpath of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now also possible to build Mule applications with Gradle: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/building-mule-apps-gradle-studio/

Adding dependencies by hand is of course also possible, like it's also possible to not use a SCM... Eventually not applying sound engineering practices when building your Mule applications will come back and bite you.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm trying to mavenize my project, but when I click "Mavenize" from the contextual menu on my project, I get the warning dialog box, but then nothing happens. It does not create a pom.xml file. I see no error in the error console.

Comment: Sounds like a Studio bug: report it to MuleSoft. In the meantime, you can create the pom.xml file by hand, using another project as a template.